# How could I check to see if a word exists in a string, and return false if it doesn't, in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, substring

Say I have a string `str = "Things to do: eat and sleep."`

How could I check if `"do: "` exists in str, case insensitive?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like this:

```
puts "yes" if str =~ /do:/i
```

To return a boolean value (from a method, presumably), compare the result of the match to `nil`:

```
def has_do(str)
    (str =~ /do:/i) != nil
end
```

Or, if you don’t like the `!= nil` then you can use `!~` instead of `=~` and negate the result:

```
def has_do(str)
    not str !~ /do:/i
end
```

But I don’t really like double negations …

Comment: Would it be possible to do this in an if block? E.g. if str =~ /do: /i puts "yes" end

Comment: @oxo Yes of course. In fact, the first code is merely a shorthand of that.

Comment: There's also the good old `!!` trick to only get a boolean result: `>> !!(str =~ /do:/i) #=> true` and `>> !!(str =~ /da:/i) #=> false`.

Comment: Why do you need to force a boolean? In Ruby, any value can be treated as if it is truthy; e.g. true / false.

Comment: @David Because that’s what the OP wanted. Normally I’d just use the expression directly, of course (see first example). But since the OP explicitly mentioned getting a boolean I showed how to do that, too.

Answer (score 4):

In ruby 1.9 you can do like this:

```
str.downcase.match("do: ") do   
  puts "yes" 
end
```

It's not exactly what you asked for, but I noticed a comment to another answer. If you don't mind using regular expressions when matching the string, perhaps there is a way to skip the downcase part to get case insensitivity.

For more info, see [String#match](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001136)

Comment: "perhaps there is a way to skip the downcase part to get case insensitivity"? `str.match(/do: /i)`

Comment: @theTinMan Oh, and it was even in the first answer as well. Need to think better next time =)

Comment: If you are running many regexs that are case-insensitive, it *might* be more efficient to downcase once and then use many case-sensitive regexs.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this:

```
str.downcase.include? "Some string".downcase
```

Answer (score 2):

If all I'm looking for is a case=insensitive substring match I usually use:

```
str.downcase['do: ']
```

9 times out of 10 I don't care where in the string the match is, so this is nice and concise.

Here's what it looks like in IRB:

```
>> str = "Things to do: eat and sleep." #=> "Things to do: eat and sleep."
>> str.downcase['do: '] #=> "do: "
>> str.downcase['foobar'] #=> nil
```

Because it returns `nil` if there is no hit it works in conditionals too.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Things to do: eat and sleep.".index(/do: /i)
```

index returns the position where the match starts, or nil if not found

You can learn more about index method here:
http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html

Or about regex here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html